# Localhost and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have five directories listed inside my sites folder that act as sites on my localserver. One of such sites is coded with codeigniter. I have gone against the natural file structure and have moved the application and system folders outside the site document root. I currently have the index.php file needed to run the application residing in the a public_html for easy transfer to my live site when it's ready for testing. While I'm on my local server how to I remove all of the extra parts of the URL.

Right now I have it showing up as :

localhost/sitename/public_html/controller

What I would prefer to do with this site is set it up so that when I open it in my browser it'll show so something like :

dev.mysite.com/controller.

As have it know the public_html is just a folder.

What sort of things in htaccess do I do?

**UPDATE:**

On my mac I have a sites folder and that houses all my sites on my local server.

```
- Sites
    -site1
        -application
        -public_hml
            index.php
            .htaccess
        -system
    -site2
        -application
        -public_html
            index.php
            .htaccess
        -system
```

I have right now have the apache in the mamp set up to where sites is the document root. Is this what I should do.

When I want to load the index file of a page it shows up as:

```
localhost/site1/public_html/index.php
```

Obviously if I were to upload this to a live server all I would have to do is go to the following link and it would work. I'm just trying to develop locally before I upload to a live server.

```
sitesname.com/index.php
```

Comment: why would you want this? Also I don't think it's possible. It may just be doable but it depends what you need it for. Some ideas included customizing your browsers code, your localhost server code, stuff I have no idea how to do.

Comment: The best way is to set it up using http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html and or to give you a idea on how to use multiple applications example http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

Comment: Have you tried writing a rewrite rule

Answer (score 5):

I believe i did this in the past. Moving the **Application** and **System** folder from **public_html** folder is a best practice. It will prevent those two folders from public direct access. After moving the folders you have to make changes in the **public_html\index.php** file. Point the system and application path one level up. Please refer to the picture below to see how i edited.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekQKi.jpg

After performing the above edit, now your application will work fine but you have to include the *index.php* segment in the URI. eg:- **localhost/index.php/welcome**. To get rid that, you will have to create an **.htaccess** file inside the *public_html* folder. please refer to the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/meF6Z.jpg

Now for your convenience, I'am attaching the rewrite code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hopefully your site will work without including the index.php in the URI like **localhost/welcome**

> > *When I want to load the index file of a page it shows up as: 
> >     **localhost/site1/public_html/index.php***
> >     *Obviously if I were to upload this to a live server all I would have to do is go to the* >>*following link and it would work. I'm just trying to develop locally before I upload to a live server.*
> >     ***sitesname.com/index.php***

Please be noted that, on your live server the domain name sitename.com is also pointing to a local directory structure like **localhost/site1/public_html/**. You can achieve the same in your localhost too. For example you can set your development site available to a  URL like **yoursite.dev/index.php**. To do that you have to perform two things.

1. Create a site in your local Apache server (name it as yoursite.dev)
2. Edit the host file to resolve the yoursite.dev

though i am using an ubuntu machine to demonstrate the configuration, I believe you could figure it out on the mac too

**Creating a site in Apache**

```
sudo nano -w /etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite.conf
```

paste the following into the file and make necessary changes

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yoursite.dev
    ServerAlias *.yoursite.dev
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html/folder

<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file. Now you have created the configuration file and need to enable the site.

```
sudo a2ensite sandbox
service apache2 restart
```

**Edit the host file to resolve the yoursite.dev**

```
sudo nano -w /etc/hosts
```

add the following line to the end and save the file

```
127.0.0.1       yoursite.dev
```

If you followed me along, now you will be able to access your development site by using the following URL: **yoursite.dev/index.php**

I hope that will help you and please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 3):

I am working in **XAMPP** on **WINDOWS**

Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`  then open the file named `hosts` in text editor. Then add this lines at the end of the file

```
127.0.0.1 sitesname.com sitesname2.com sitesname3.com
```

Eg : [image: hosts file content]

After that go to `XAMPP` installed location

For me its : `E:\xampp` . Then go to folder `apache\conf\extra` in it. Find the file named `httpd-vhosts.conf` ( `E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` )

then add

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\site1"
    ServerName sitesname.com
<Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\site2"
    ServerName sitesname2.com
<Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Eg : [image: vertual host setup]

Save the file and restart the `Apache` server and check **sitesname.com**.

It works for me.

**Note** : Sometimes Folder added outside `E:\xampp\htdocs\` can't accessed by Apache

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change it in your routes

[yournameyouwant] = "controller/index";

[yournameyouwant] = "folder/controller/index";

Here are some htaccess I use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may see hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ .

Using editor, you have to add following code:

```
127.0.0.1  local.site1.com
127.0.0.1  local.site2.com
```

After that, you must add this at C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\site1"
    ServerName local.site1.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\site1"
    ServerName local.site2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And, restart xampp.
You need to edit .htaccess file of each site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Done

Comment: I'm on a mac so where do I enter 127.0.0.1  local.site1.com
127.0.0.1  local.site2.com at?

Comment: @user2576961 you can enter it on the host file. use the command `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

- Setup a virtual host (my.local.dev) in apache that connects to your local folder.
- Trick your OS into using http://my.local.dev by adding it to your hosts file.
- (restart apache)
- Still failing? htaccess in your public html or change codeigniter routing